# Without using any Sylow theorem, if every element is a $p$-element then $G$ is a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

How can we prove the following theorem without using any Sylow theorem?

Let $p$ be a prime. In a finite group $G$, if every element is a $p$-element then $G$ is a $p$-group.

Or is it possible to generalize the following theorem to three or more subgroups?

If $H_{1},H_{2} \leq G$ then $\lvert H_{1}H_{2}\rvert = \frac{\lvert H_{1}\rvert\lvert H_{2}\rvert}{\lvert H_{1}\cap H_{2}\rvert}$

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that a group has a subgroup of order $p$ for each prime $p$ dividing its order is known as Cauchy's theorem. It has a simpler proof that Sylow's theorems (many proofs of the Sylow theorems even make use of it).

Comment: The order of a product of subgroups can be used as part of a proof, but the only proofs I know are highly non-trivial to come up with without several hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to avoid using Cauchy's theorem, you can use center equation and induction:

Let $G$ be a smallest counterexample. Let $q \neq p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$. Then, $G$ is simple(why?). Use center equation to get the contradiction $q\mid \lvert Z(G)\rvert$.

Comment: Nice way to do it. (This argument can be turned into a proof of Cauchy's theorem though with only a few extra steps).